# Overlapping text in uicollection view headers for different sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I added different text labels to my collectionview headers for each section in swift.I use uireusableviews for headers. My problem is when I scroll the text in the labels of different sections overlap with each other.I tried setting the text label to "" before changing the text but the problem still persists.

```html
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if(kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader){
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "h", for: indexPath) as? UICollectionViewCell
        let txtlab = UILabel()
        txtlab.text = ""
        if(indexPath.section%2 == 0){
            txtlab.text = "Header"}
        else{
            txtlab.text = "another header"
        }
        cell?.addSubview(txtlab)
        txtlab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        txtlab.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        txtlab.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        cell?.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell!
    }
```

[Image of problem faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdvSS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the views before you generate the new ones.

Put this your method that creates the header at the top.

```
for view in myView {
myView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Edit, I didn’t see your code.

Your first issue is that you’re creating a new label for every cell. You should create a outlet so that each cell is hooked up to the label. Then you should be able to change the header.